# What is the use of the "please edit this question to explain how it is different"?

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-questions

My question was <del>marked</del> flagged as a duplicate (it was not closed) so I got a note next to the title explaining that it may have an answer somewhere else and suggesting to "edit this question to explain how it is different".

I did.

I still see a yellow window with "This question may already have an answer here:" next to the title of my question:

[image]

Am I the only one to see it?

If so: why would I need to see it?

If not: how to get rid of it? I explained in my question that this is not a duplicate, but this one "duplicate" flag still trumps my explanations.
If this is the right approach then why bothering asking someone to update his question, as the updates does not clear the flag anyway (and still suggests to the millions who will stumble upon it that it is a duplicate)

Comment: Are you saying you expected it to go away after you edited the question? It only goes away if the question is re-opened... Until it is reopened, it's still considered a duplicate by the system and therefore you get said message.

Comment: @KevinB: the question was not closed, it just got flagged as duplicate (but is still open (and answered, and answer accepted))

Comment: gotcha. I forget those exist, I can't cast them.

Comment: After you edited, then, someone else likely flagged the post, which brings the banner back. Or maybe even while you edited, and they didn't see your edit.

Comment: And.. only you see that banner. It'l go away when the flag ages away or is handled.

Comment: @KevinB: thanks for the explanation. I do not really understand why I would need to see it (I obviously know that there was a suggestion of a duplicate, as I edited the question to reflect that) - but anyway.

Comment: If you think you have better solution (like "let system automatically figure out if my change clarifies why it is not duplicate", or even better - "let SO automatically edit my post to add necessary details and explanation why it is not duplicate") - please suggest one as feature-request. Otherwise I think keeping banner while close vote/flags are active is the best solution so far.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: I feel that the current system assumes that a flag someone puts on a question cannot be reversed after careful edition and. In other words, more trust is put on a random reader than on the author of the question who cannot edit it in a way which would make the flag go away, no matter how carefully he revisits the question. This is just a matter of whom SO trusts more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are the only one who see that banner while close votes/flags are present on the question.

Edits do not clear duplicate votes/flags as there (at the moment) is no automated system that can analyze the edit and confirm that all necessary clarifications are made.

The only way to get rid of it immediately is to use gold-hammer to close and immediately re-open the question to remove all close votes/flags. While definitely an option it is abuse of gold tag privilege even if post properly edited to clarify why it is not duplicate (not voting to close and letting votes to age out is proper way to handle such posts).

Comment: That's abusing your privileges *even if* you honestly don't think it's a duplicate.

Comment: i didn't see saying that in the answer as a suggestion that it should be done, it simply points out that it is possible to have it removed sooner by invalidating the flag.

Comment: @Servy good point. Indeed it reads as endorsement to do that - editing the post.

Comment: *no automated system that can analyze the edit and confirm that all necessary clarifications are made* ... and therefore a flag which is not checked either has more importance than any kind of re-edit of the OP. I am not whining here, just trying to understand where the trust id put.

Comment: @WoJ SO automatically trusts OP to put content *they want* in the post (including giving OP binding vote on edit reviews), but can't trust OP to put content that makes sense (that why we have review queues). Don't forget that there is significantly more people who have barely any experience with SO to know what good edits are... there probably handful of people who have a lot of experience successfully editing posts to explain "not duplicate" - even 2-5-10K   reputation may not be enough to completely trust users to provide good edit (indeed you can make feature request and use 2K to start)